# Is it possible to add an input field to Wagtails custom bulk actions?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Is it possible to add an input field to Wagtails [custom bulk actions](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/custom_bulk_actions.html)?

In the template from the documentation example there is a block called `form_section`. Here I want to add a separate form to add another input field. Another position would be possible as well, of course.

```py
<!-- /path/to/confirm_bulk_import.html -->

# ...

{% block form_section %}
{% if images %}
    {% trans 'Yes, import' as action_button_text %}
    {% trans "No, don't import" as no_action_button_text %}
    # Can I use my own confirmation form here? How about its view?:
    {% include 'wagtailadmin/bulk_actions/confirmation/form.html' with action_button_class="serious" %}
{% else %}
    {% include 'wagtailadmin/bulk_actions/confirmation/go_back.html' %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock form_section %}
```

**I would love to bulk select** `Image` **instances to add them to a** `Page`. So I need to have a `ChoiceField` to select the `Page`. This would also require a customized `View` for the logic behind this "import". The latter is not the question. I am just wondering how I can add this input field and alter the view of a these marvelous bulk actions.

Standard bulk actions for images in Wagtail also include "Add images to collection":
[image: Standard bulk actions for images in Wagtail also include "Add images to collection"]

The following is how the second step of this action looks like. I would love to add a custom bulk action in this sense to add images to a page (via a `ImagePageRelation` / `InlinePanel`)

[image: This is how the second step of this action looks like. I would love to add a custom bulk action in this sense to add images to a page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wagtail admin portal is using pure HTML and CSS. So everything coming to the `python` side is received via a HTML form. That means every button click in UI should associate with a `HTML form` and from wagtail side you can find it in the `request`.

### Execute Action Method

If you went through the [bulk action documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/custom_bulk_actions.html#custom-bulk-actions), you will find that after the `form` is submitted, `execute_action` class method will be executed. Now you need to understand the parameters of this method.

```py
@classmethod
def execute_action(cls, objects, **kwargs):
    raise NotImplementedError("execute_action needs to be implemented")
```

As this is a class method, the first parameter is the class type which this method is on. You can learn more about class methods in [the python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

The 2nd parameter `objects` is the list of objects that you have selected for this bulk operation. To be precise, this is the list of objects that you have selected with the correct permission level. In the default implementation, permission is given for all the objects. But you can override this behavior.

```py
def check_perm(self, obj):
    return True
```

You can override this method in your custom bulk action class and check permission for each object. As the `objects` parameter, you will receive the only objects which have `check_perm(obj)==True`, from the list of objects you selected.

The 3rd parameter of `execute_action` class method is a keyworded argument list (a dictionary to be precise). This dictionary is obtained by calling the following method.

```py
def get_execution_context(self):
    return {}
```

Default behavior of this method is to return empty dictionary. But you can override this to send anything. Because `execute_action` is a class method, it can't access the instant variables. So this method is very helpful to pass instance variables to `execute_action` class method.

### Lets look at an example.

```py
@hooks.register('register_bulk_action')
class CustomBulkAction(ImageBulkAction):
    display_name = _("A Thing")
    aria_label = _("A thing to do")
    action_type = "thing"
    template_name = "appname/bulk/something.html"

    def get_execution_context(self):
        print(self.request)
        return super().get_execution_context()
```

If you run this example, you can see the data submitted from the `HTML form`.

```
<WSGIRequest: POST '/admin/bulk/image/customimage/thing/?next=%2Fadmin%2Fimages%2F&id=1'>
```

### Override the HTML Form

In the bulk action template, you can't find any HTML `<form></form>` tag. It is because the form with action buttons are in `wagtailadmin/bulk_actions/confirmation/form.html` file that you have import in the template. You can create the copy of that file and change it's behavior.

```html
<form action="{{ submit_url }}" method="POST">
    {% include 'wagtailadmin/shared/non_field_errors.html' %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block form_fields %}
        <!-- Custom Fields goes here -->
    {% endblock form_fields %}
    <input type="submit" value="{{ action_button_text }}" class="button {{ action_button_class }}" />
    <a href="{{ next }}" class="button button-secondary">{{ no_action_button_text }}</a>
</form>
```

You can add custom fields you need in the area that I mentioned above sample code and values of those additional fields will be there in `self.request.POST`  parameter. This is the easiest way to get something from the template to python side.

### Django Forms

But that is not the best way. Django recommends using forms for these purposes. You can find more about Django forms in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).

Almost every place that there is a form in a wagtail template, there is a associated Django form. In this case, the instance variable `form_class` is used to associate a bulk action template with a Django form.

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    extra_field = forms.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            required=True,
        )

@hooks.register('register_bulk_action')
class CustomBulkAction(ImageBulkAction):
    display_name = _("A Thing")
    aria_label = _("A thing to do")
    action_type = "thing"
    template_name = "appname/bulk/something.html"
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_execution_context(self):
        print(self.cleaned_form.data)
        return super().get_execution_context()
```

And very simply, I will add all the form fields to the template as in the below sample code.

```html
<form action="{{ submit_url }}" method="POST">
    {% include 'wagtailadmin/shared/non_field_errors.html' %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% block form_fields %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock form_fields %}
    <input type="submit" value="{{ action_button_text }}" class="button {{ action_button_class }}" />
    <a href="{{ next }}" class="button button-secondary">{{ no_action_button_text }}</a>
</form>
```

Now this will print the data received from the HTML form. What we need to do is to pass the form data as `kwargs` to the `execute_action` class method.

### Final Example

```py
@hooks.register('register_bulk_action')
class CustomBulkAction(ImageBulkAction):
    display_name = _("A Thing")
    aria_label = _("A thing to do")
    action_type = "thing"
    template_name = "appname/bulk/something.html"
    form_class = MyForm

    def get_execution_context(self):
        data = super().get_execution_context()
        data['form'] = self.cleaned_form
        return data
    
    @classmethod
    def execute_action(cls, objects, **kwargs):
        print("KWARGS:", kwargs)
        print(kwargs['form'].cleaned_data['extra_field'])
        # Do what you want
        return 0, 0
```

I believe this was helpful and answered all the questions related to bulk action submission.

With `forms.ModelChoiceField` in your form, you can get values from Django `Model`s and pass them to the HTML field. You have to pass a `queryset` in the constructor.

```py
extra_field = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        required=True,
        queryset=Collection.objects.order_by("name"),
    )
```

Comment: I am amazed by this detailed answer! Thank you very much, @Ramesh-X

Comment: @Fuchsi no problem. It's been a long time since I contributed last. Wanted to be bit detailed.. 